# Trouble building FB.api query

Tags: javascript, facebook, pagination, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

OK so I'm working on a Facebook Group Feed that loads more results, but I'm having trouble building the initial query for it all to work.

In the first `if` statement below, you can see where I put the parts of the query into variables and then call the function, passing those variables. This all works fine...

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
// Logged into your app and Facebook.
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

var path = '/', 
    method = 'POST',
    params = {
      batch: [
        {method : 'GET', name : 'user', relative_url : '/me?fields=id,name,picture'},
        {method: 'GET', name : 'post-ids', relative_url: '/group-id/feed?fields=fields{with field expansion}',omit_response_on_success : false}
      ]
    };

loadFeed(path, method, params);

}
```

The funciton below is where I'm having trouble. The first time the function is called, I need to put those three variables together into one, and call it with FB.api. You can see the function here:

```
function loadFeed(path, method, params) {

    console.log('------------------');
    console.log(path + ', ' + method + ', ' + params);

    if(path != 'undefined') {
      if(method != 'undefined') {
        if(params != 'undefined') { var query = '{\'' + path + '\', \'' + method + '\', ' + params + '}'; } 
      } 
      else { var query = path; }
    } 

    $('#load-more').css('display', 'hidden');

    FB.api(query, function (response) {
        console.log(response);

      // first time page loads, response[0] is the login, and response[1] is the feed
      // each time after that, response[0] is the feed

      if(response.length > 1) {
        var membody = JSON.parse(response[0].body),
            feed = JSON.parse(response[1].body);
      } else {
        var feed = JSON.parse(response);
      }

      if(feed.paging) {

        if(feed.paging.next) {

          var load_more = '<div id="load-more"><center>Load more</center></div>',
              method = '',
              params = '';

          $('#feed').append(load_more);

          $('#load-more').click( function() {
            loadFeed(feed.paging.next);
          });

        }

      }

    });
}
```

On the first call of this function, I get this error:

```
error: Object
    code: 2500
    message: "Unknown path components: /', 'POST', [object Object]}"
    type: "OAuthException"
```

This seems to tell me that I've basically put the query together wrong, but I've tried a few different things and none of it is working. You can see in the error message that there's a missing single quote at the beginning of the query, and I've not been able to figure out how to keep the single quote there.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Also, if you know a better way to do all this then I'd appreciate that as well!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building your Javascript API call with HTTP API parameters.

To query JS API for user:

```js
FB.api(
  "/me", // or "/99999999999" the user's id
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
    }

);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

To query JS API for group:

```js
FB.api(
  "/{group-id}",
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
    }
  }
);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group